# How to iterate over numerically named object properties

Tags: c#, oop, loops

So I have a horribly designed class that I can't change that has properties like this:

```
object.Color1
object.Color2
object.Color3
```

etc...

How can I iterate through those with a for loop. In other words, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
{
   string PropertyName = "Color" + i;

   if (object.PropertyName != "") 
   { 
       // do something
   }
}
```

Obviously this code wouldn't work but it gives you an idea of what I'm after. I have to do some processing on each property and I don't want to repeat my code 40 times. :) A loop would be perfect, I'm just not sure how to create the name of the property on the fly.

**EDIT**: Ok so I've tried the following code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++ )
            {
                var type = pendingProduct.GetType();

                var colorProperty = type.GetProperty("Color" + i);
                string colorValue = colorProperty.GetValue(type, null).ToString();

                var colorSkuProperty = type.GetProperty("Color" + i + "SKU");
                string colorSkuValue = colorSkuProperty.GetValue(type, null).ToString();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(colorValue)) continue;

                ProductColor color = new ProductColor {Color = colorValue, ProductSizes = productSizes};
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(colorSkuValue)) color.SKU = colorSkuValue;
            }
```

I'm getting an error "Object does not match target type" on this line:

```
string colorValue = colorProperty.GetValue(type, null).ToString();
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You need to get the value of your object instance, not the `System.Type` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for reflection:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(SomeType).GetProperty("Color" + i);
string value = (string)property.GetValue(obj, null);
```

Note that this will be slow.
If you do it many times, you can make it faster by caching `Delegate.CreateDelegate(..., property.GetGetMethod())` in an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection for that:

```
var type = myObject.GetType();
var property = type.GetProperty("Color1");
var value = property.GetValue(myObject, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do to help finding.

```
$abc = array(
 'a' => 'world',
 'b' => 'good',
);

$object = (object) $abc;

foreach($object as $k) 
{
  var_dump($object);
}
```

Comment: php? there is a C# tag on the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the property by name. In your example you can use:

```
var pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName);
var val = pi.GetValue(obj,null);
```

In order to obtain the value of the property which name is PropertyName. You should check for pi != null because if a requested property does not exists null is returned. 
If the function you are writing is time critical, you should anyway pay attention that reflection has some performance drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at InvokeMethod...

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx)

[Example at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CallMethodNameInString.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of...

```
Type type = this.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
{
    // Check property is the one you want
    // and carry out your code...
}
```

Also, If you have access to the code I.E. you can change the internals but want to leave the public API intact you could just add the information to a private collection when the object is constructed. The collection could then be exposed by a public property for you to iterate over. A bit hacky but an alternative to using reflection.